# Add wp-link-pages to post

Tags: posts, pages, pagination, single, wp-link-pages

I am trying to add `wp-link-pages` function to my post where I have images split into many pages in that single post. I already have next and prev button whose functionality is written javascript. I find it difficult if I wanna skip from image1 to image14. So I am not sure how to achieve this wordpress as I am a nooby. Here is the code I am using to split the post images into multiple pages.

```
<?php 
                        global $post;
                        if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) )
                        {
                            $id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
                            $exclude = $id;
                        }
                        $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $post->ID,
                        'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'order' => 'DESC',
                        'orderby'  => 'menu_order DESC', 'exclude' => $exclude) );

                        $imgid = 1;

                        foreach($attachments as $attachment){

                            ?>
                                <div class="comix" style="display:none; margin:0 auto; position:absolute;"><h2>Page <?php echo $imgid; ?></h2><img src="<?php echo $attachment->guid;?>" style="margin:0 auto;" /><br /><p><?php echo $attachment->post_content;?></p></div>

                            <?
                            $imgid++;
                        }

                    ?>
```

I have this navigation

```
 <div class="navigation" style="bottom:100px;"><a href="#" class="prev" ><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/images/arrow-prev1.png" style="2px solid #EE1C25 ; width: 100px; height: 100px;"  /></a><div style="float:right; cursor:pointer;"><a href="#" class="next" ><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/images/arrow-next1.png" style="2px solid #EE1C25 ; width: 100px; height: 100px;" /></a></div><div class="clear"></div></div>
```

whose functionality is given by the following javascript

```
 <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        //comicles
        nextClicked = false;
        prevClicked = false;
        $('.getstarted-content > div.comix').hide();
        $('.getstarted-content > div.comix:first-child').fadeIn();
        $('.getstarted-content > div.comix:first-child').addClass('activeComicle');
        var Height = $('.activeComicle > img').css('height');
        $('ul.getstarted li').click(function(){             
            $gscontent = $('img', this).attr('class');
            $('.getstarted-content > div.comix').fadeOut();
            $('.getstarted-content > div.comix').removeClass('activeComicle');
            $('.getstarted-content div#'+$gscontent+"").fadeIn();
            $('.getstarted-content div#'+$gscontent+"").addClass('activeComicle');

        });
        $('.prev').hide();


        $('.prev').click(function(){
            if(prevClicked == false){
                prevClicked = true;$('.getstarted-content > div.comix').fadeOut();              
                obj = $('div.activeComicle').prev();
                $(obj).fadeIn();
                $('.getstarted-content > div.comix').removeClass('activeComicle');
                $(obj).addClass('activeComicle');

                $('.next').show();

                if($(obj).prev().html() == null || $(obj).prev().html()==''){
                    $('.prev').hide();
                }
                var Height = $('.activeComicle > img').height();
                $('#photos').css('height', ''+(Height+75)+'');
                prevClicked = false;
            }
            //prevcheck();
            //nextcheck();
            window.scrollTo(0,0);
            return false;
        });
        $('.next').click(function(){
            if(nextClicked == false){
                nextClicked = true;
                $('.getstarted-content > div.comix').fadeOut();             
                obj = $('div.activeComicle').next();
                $(obj).fadeIn();
                $('.getstarted-content > div.comix').removeClass('activeComicle');
                $(obj).addClass('activeComicle');
                $('.prev').show();
                if($(obj).next().html() == null || $(obj).next().html()==''){
                    $('.next').hide();
                }
                $('#photos').height($('.activeComicle  > img').height()+75);
                nextClicked = false;
            }
            window.scrollTo(0,0);
            return false;
        });


        setTimeout(init, 2000);



    });
    function init(){
            jQuery('#photos').css('visibility', 'visible');
            jQuery('#loading').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            jQuery('#photos').height(jQuery('.activeComicle > img').height() + 75);
    }
</script>
```

I am trying to achieve something like

```
<< Previous Page | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | Next Page >>
```

I hope I am clear. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question.

Here is the javascript that I wrote which works 100% smooth.

```
<script>
$(document).on("scroll mousedown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.which > 0 || e.type === "mousedown" || e.type === "mousewheel") {
        $('html,body').stop();
    }
});


pageSize = 1;

showPage = function(page) {
    $(".comix").hide();
    $(".comix").each(function(n) {
        if (n >= pageSize * (page - 1) && n < pageSize * page)
            $(this).show();

    });        
}

showPage(1)

$("#pagin li").click(function() {
    $("#pagin li").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(".single-post-content").offset().top}, 400);

    showPage(parseInt($(this).text())) 
});

    $('#pagin li').each(function(i) {
    if ( i === 1 ) {
       $(this).addClass('current');
    }
});

var $first = $('li:first', 'ol'),
    $last = $('li:last', 'ol');

$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 39) { 
        var $next, $selected = $(".current");
            $next = $selected.next('li').length ? $selected.next('li') : $first;
            $selected.removeClass("current");
            $next.addClass("current");
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(".single-post-content").offset().top}, 400);
            showPage(parseInt($next.text())) 
    }
});


$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 37) { 
            var $prev, $selected = $(".current");

            $prev = $selected.prev('li').length ? $selected.prev('li') : $last;
            $selected.removeClass("current");
            $prev.addClass("current");
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(".single-post-content").offset().top}, 400);
            showPage(parseInt($prev.text())) 

}
    });


</script>
```